# how do I get my eclipse CPP lunar to show ouput?

Tags: c, eclipse, console, output

I just installed Eclipse CPP lunar for my windows 64, and I ran a couple of C code (not c++), but for some reason I can get to the console to show any output, I did the build PATH in the environment part in my properties, but still can't get anything to show. I run my C code in cmd, and everything was perfect! what should I do? do I need to add new flags, it seems the code can run well just no ouput.

update: I watched a video on youtube, and I run some c++ code and the output console is perfect for some reason, just C code I can't get any output. did I built the path wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.mochaz.com/2012/03/solution-for-no-console-output-in.html there is a workaround, where you have to add the path of the MinGW  compiler (which you most likely use) to the Environment variable of your project (project specific settings).

1. Goto `Project->Properties->Run/Debug Settings`, choose the .exe file    and press Edit
2. In the `Environment` tag, press New, and set it as: Name: `PATH`, Value: `C:\MinGW\bin`

Comment: for some reason my c++ code can show output, but any .c files when I run console just shows nothing

Comment: on top of console there is a line says terminated midterm2.exe(name of the exe)

Comment: Maybe you can find more info in this forum thread: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/197552/

Comment: really confused by it